Correct request from angular 18 with bearer token is getting null header in spring
I have my angular project working. In step 1, I'm able to login and get the token from my spring boot application. I save this token to localstorage. This request is posible because is not blocked by authentication.
The problem is when I want to do a request with Bearer token. My Angular app send a request with, appearently, a correct header, but my Spring app it is not able to detect it. The most surprising is that if I call the same request with Postman, it works fine.
First of all, I'm using these versions:

Angular: 18.2.8
rxjs 7.8.1
typescript 5.5.4
zone.js 0.14.10
Spring boot 3.3.4

One of examples calls from Angular is this (test function):
component.ts
test() {
    this.userService.getUserByUsername('user').subscribe({
      next: (data:any) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: (err) => console.log('Fail', err)
    })
  }

user.Service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  url: string;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
    this.url = environment.domainUrl + '/users';
  }

  public getUserByUsername(username:string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/username/${username}`).pipe(
      tap((response:any) => {
        if(response.user){
          console.log(response.user)
        }
      })
    );
  }

}

auth.interceptor.ts
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
    console.log("Intercepting Requests");
    const authService = inject(AuthService);
    const token = authService.getToken();
    let authReq = req;

    if (token) {
        authReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization:'Bearer ' + token
            }
        });
        console.log("Token added to request:", token);
        console.log(authReq);
    } else {
        console.log("No token found");
    }

    return next(authReq);
};

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http';
import { authInterceptor } from './services/auth/auth.interceptor';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), 
    provideRouter(routes), 
    provideAnimationsAsync(), 
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([authInterceptor]))
  ]
};

Now, we can see the browser console. One of the requests:

If we search the request headers, we can see it:

However, in Spring boot app I'm getting authHeader as a null.
snippet getToken
private String getTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if(StringUtils.hasText(authHeader) && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
        {
            return authHeader.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

I have to clarify that if I use the same token in Postman, I get the correct response.
I'm very lost with that issue, I don't know what is happening. Thanks for your help.

Please show the code where you register the interceptor in app.config.ts / app.module.ts

Hi @JSONDerulo I've edited the question and I've added app.config.ts code. Thanks!

The error says that you have a CORS issue. In your Spring Boot app, add "http://localhost:4200" to the list of allowed origins in your security configuration.

You can find an example in the Spring Security docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html

Yes, if I execute Chrome without web security (chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security) it works perfect. But in normal conditions it's not working. If I add cors disabled it is working OMG! Thanks!

Question solved, I added the solution :) Thanks to all, specially to @DanielSprohar

The solution is the following one:
In the Spring boot application, I have just added the cors disable option and the OPTIONS matcher permission in securityfilterchain.
Now, the securityFilterChain of SecurityConfig is like this:
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authRequest ->
                        authRequest
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                                ...
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

Thanks to all for your help, specially to Daniel Sprohar.
